# UML for delegation pattern

Tags: objective-c, delegates, uml

I would like to modelize the delegation pattern (for objective-C) in UML. What is the correct presentation for it please?

For example:

My class BaseXMLParser have a delegate which conforme to ParserDelegate Interface. Methods in ParserDelegate will be implement in UI class

ps: sorry for my English

[image: Delegation pattern]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `<<ParserDelegate>>` you should use `<<Interface>>`, and instead of `delegate` your interface's name is `ParserDelegate`. You also don't have to write the methods that are defined in the interface (`ParserDelegate`) in the implementing class (`UI`). I would also give the reference from `BaseXMLParser` to `ParserDelegate` a direction, since I see no reason that the delegate should call the client class.